# How to pass UI data to ViewModel function when using data binding for onClickListeners?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I have extensively searched for this issue but have not yet found a reasonable solution.

What I'm trying to do is simply set up an onClickListener using the data binding format in the layout:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> subjectsViewModel.onClickAdd()}"
```

where subjectsViewModel is a layout variable to which I pass the ViewModel in the fragment.

What I want is to pass the currently entered edit text data to onClickAdd() function.
The only solution I have found yet is to use two way data binding but I do not think it should be required for setting up such a basic fuctionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the view reference and get the text from TextView after casting it back to TextView from View. something like this.

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> subjectsViewModel.onClickAdd(view)}"
```

and in your view model just create something like this.

```
fun onClickAdd(view: View){
 val myText = (view as TextView).text ?: ""
 //here use text 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First give an id to your `EditText`. Lets say the id is `edittext`.
Then do it like this.

```
android:onClick="@{() -> subjectsViewModel.onClickAdd(edittext.getText().toString())}"
```

Comment: I tested it before posting answer, this was working.

Comment: @buckets Check if your viewmodel is not null.